# Правильный путь к файлу или иная ошибка

Tags: android, java

Добрый день! Возникла следующая проблема, надеюсь на вашу помощь. Сохраняю в конструкторе класса некоторый Bitmap, запоминаю адрес, но когда обращаюсь к нему, то ничего по этому адресу не находит. С чем это может быть связано? Код в конструкторе:

```
try {
        OutputStream stream = this.context.openFileOutput("icon_"+String.valueOf(this.id),Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        (BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArr, 0, byteArr.length)).compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,90,stream);
        this.icon = "icon_"+String.valueOf(this.id);
        stream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

код при проверке существования в главной активности

```
if (context.getFileStreamPath("icon_"+String.valueOf(data.ads.get(1).id)).exists()){
        mTextView.setText(mTextView.getText()+"\n путь "+"icon_"+String.valueOf(data.ads.get(1).id)+" не найден!");
    }else{
        mTextView.setText(mTextView.getText()+"\n путь "+"icon_"+String.valueOf(data.ads.get(1).id)+" найден!");
    }
```

Соответственно в текствью выводит, что путь не найден. Тестирую в эмуляторе с андроид студией.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите ещё раз внимательно в ваш `if` и добавьте в него отрицание.

Comment: Действительно, что-то прошляпил. Но в то же время ведь не работает код

    mImageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(data.ads.get(1).icon));

Пустое место остается вместо картинки (хотя если не сохранять в файловую систему и сразу вставить, то картинка есть). Собственно из-за этого и поставил этот if.